# Docker build Rename PATH1 PATH2: Access is denied

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile, so I run the command

```
docker build --tag esma .
```

but every time I run the command at some point during the building process it says similar to this

```
rename C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-894656615 C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\f858b3a31e4464e040166d10a04048620ecb75b47ba910e363de8682ed268711: Access is denied.
```

or this

```
failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-871967704 C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\3fd27ecef6a323f5ea7f3fde1f7b87a2dbfb1afa797f88fd7d20e8dbdc856f67: Access is denied.
```

but with varying Paths each time. Before when I ran a Docker build command for the same Dockerfile, it worked after I restarted my PC. Now, after restarting nothing changes.

Could this issue be because I have already built this Dockerfile and that location is already taken? If you would like to see my Dockerfile I can post it, but I don't think it's important besides the fact it's adding things that were added in previous image build that has since been deleted.

Comment: It sounds like a file permissions issue on the base host you're running the commands from. I would recommend checking the user you're using has write permissions to the C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\ directory.

Comment: I do have write permissions to that directory.

Comment: Write permission on all files in there as well?

Comment: Yeah I have all read/write permissions for that directory. I was not using an elevated Powershell window earlier, so I am trying it now.